# Issue with Inputs in jQuery

Tags: jquery, syntax, input

Kind of new to learning jQuery, I wrote this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert($("#myInput").value);
        alert($("#myInput").length);
    });
</script>

<input id="myInput" value="Hello, World!" type="text" />
```

I don't know why it is not why it always shows me:

```
undefined
1
```

While the expected outptu is:

```
Hello, World!
13
```

Please advice me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Format your code properly!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get value of a text field using JavaScript? (jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905906/how-to-get-value-of-a-text-field-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kind of questions have been discussed and answered many times. Always, do a search before answering. Let me give you some suggestions.

1. You have built-in functions like [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), which is mainly used for getting the current value of the form inputs, when you have different types of them like textbox, checkbox, radio, textarea, and each of them use different types. So, change your first script this way:

   ```
   alert($("#myInput").val());
   ```
2. The object returned by `$("#myInput")` would be a jQuery collection of elements. So, there is only one `<input type="text" id="myInput" />`. You need to use `$("#myInput").val().length`, and that gives the length of the value in the textbox. So, change your second script to:

   ```
   alert($("#myInput").val().length);
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I am very new to jQuery.

Comment: Er... Why the downvote? Seriously?

Answer (score 3):

`value` isn't a valid jQuery method. You probably want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($("#myInput").val());
    alert($("#myInput").val().length);
});
```

The `.val` method (with no parameters passed) returns the matched element's current value (if applicable). With normal/basic Javascript, you would have used `.value` on an element object, but `$()` returns a "jQuery object" that is nothing like an `HTMLElement` (what is returned from `document.getElementById`). So a jQuery object doesn't have a `value` property and returns `undefined`. Whereas `document.getElementById("myInput").value` (and adding `.length` at the end) would've worked for you.

The `.length` property is a basic property of string variables in Javascript (and arrays). Since the result returned from `$()` is an array-like object, it has a `length` property that represents how many elements matched your selector. In your case, it matched 1, the element with the id of "myInput".

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I am very new to jQuery.

Comment: @StackOverflow: jQuery has great documentation: http://api.jquery.com/. It's worth spending some time just having a look at what all those methods are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `val()` method of jQuery object, try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var value = $("#myInput").val()
    alert('Value: ' + value);
    alert('Value: ' + value.length);
});
```